# Laravel - QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'value' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have a ManyToMany relation

```
user_id | measurement_id | value
```

**Search query**

```
->whereHas('measurement', function($q) use ( $from, $to )
        {
              foreach (array_combine($from, $to) as $f => $t) {
                    if(!empty($f) && !empty($t))
                    {
                      $q->whereRaw('( value between ? and  ?)', array($f, $t));

                    }
                }
        })
```

and i get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'value' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate
```

Tired with the following query

```
$q->whereRaw('( users_measurement.value between ? and  ?)', array($f, $t));
```

Than i get this error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users_measurement.value' in 'where clause'
```

Could please someone help me out?

**Edit more specific queries**

*Users model*

```
public function measurement()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Measurement', 'users_measurement')->withPivot('value');
    }
```

**Search Query in my controller**

```
function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;


    }



public function search()
    {
    $users = $this->user
             ->whereHas('measurement', function($q) use ( $from, $to )
            {
                  foreach (array_combine($from, $to) as $f => $t) 
                  {
                        if(!empty($f) && !empty($t))
                        {
                           $q->whereRaw('( users.measurement.value between ? and  ?)', array($f, $t));
                        }
                    }
            })
           ->where('approved', '=', 1)
           ->where('activated', '=', 1)
           ->paginate(15);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete query?

Comment: now its ok, sorry about the delay